# Retrieving data from database using prepared statement

Tags: php, database, oop, fetch

I'm having problem retrieving my data from my database. Here's my code:

```
function login($email, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM lms_admin_users WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            // echo data from table like $data["name"]; <----
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

What I want to know is the equivalent of `while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` to replace my existing code (in OOP way) `while ($stmt->fetch())` and make it fetch the datas using `$data["name"]`

Comment: Please describe the error you get, up to which point all goes well. Check if `$stmt === false` right after you prepare the statement, check for error messages from the DB (`$this->conn->error`)

Comment: Okay, what I want to know is the equivalent of `while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` for OOP prepared statement. I don't get any errors, what my problem is I can't fetch my data using this `while ($stmt->fetch())` nor `while ($data=$stmt->fetch())`

Comment: It is currently not clear from your question that your problem really is that you have no idea how to access the retrieved data once you arrive in the `while` loop. Please put this in your question, because it risks to be closed soon for being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell PHP in which variable(s) to store the result. There are two ways to do this:

1. with [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), and then [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) on the statement object, or
2. with [`get_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php), and then [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (or other `fetch_*` variant) on the result object

## 1. bind_result

With this solution you bind variable(s) to the `SELECT` list, and while looping with `fetch` PHP will put the new data in those variable(s):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM lms_admin_users WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();    
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);  // <- Add; #args = #cols in SELECT
if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $id, $name;  // <-- then you can do this.
    }
}
```

## 2. get_result

Instead of `bind_result` you can use `get_result`, which will give a result object which you can fetch each row from as an associative array:

```
//...
//  $stmt->store_result();   // <- Remove: does not work together with next statement
$result = $stmt->get_result();   // <--- add this instead
if($result->num_rows == 1) {     // <--- change to $result->...!
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $data['id'], $data['name'];  // <--- available in $data
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution works for me but it only get the ID even I change the variable, the second one gives me an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\laragon\sad\admin\inc\class.library.php on line 32`. I need `if($stmt->num_rows == 1)` to verify if that user exist using the email address provided, then it will go to the `while ($stmt->fetch())` statement to fetch the password data for me to be able to use `password_verify()` function and give the user a session to access the member's area. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you update your question with a SELECT statement that has more than one field in the SELECT list, so I can tune my answer to that? The `Fatal error` means that the call to `get_result` failed: I correct my answer. Apparently `store_result` and `get_result` cannot be used in such combination. I also added the num_rows call, which is different in the 2nd solution.

Comment: I tried the second option and it works! I just changed something in SQL query from id to *. Thank you so much, you saved me!

Comment: OK, thanks for having done that. If you ask your new question and want me to look at it as well, please feel free to post a link to it in these comments once you have created the question. That way I will get notified.

Comment: I have a new question, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091778/how-to-echo-variable-from-the-class-function-to-the-other-file

Comment: @trincot why do you `bind_result($id, $name)` if the SELECT is only retrieving the `id` column.  That snippet looks broken to me.