# How to echo variable from the class function to the other file

Tags: php, oop, echo

I am just a beginner at OOP PHP. What I want to happen is to echo the variable from the class inside the function to other file. Please take a look at this code:

in `class.library.php` file:

```
class db_connect {

    // Other functions and variables here

    function settings() {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM lms_admin_settings";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name = $data["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

and in `index.php` file:

```
include("class.library.php");
$data = new db_connect;
$data->settings();
```

what I want to happen is to simply echo the variable named `$name` from `settings()` function of class named `db_connect` to `index.php` file.

I tried something like this:

```
include("class.library.php");
$data = new db_connect;
$data->settings();
echo $name; // I tried this but didn't work, I put this just to make things more clearly.
```

Please tell me the correct way of doing that.

PS: Pardon for what terms that I've used to explain my problem. I am just a beginner. You are always welcome to correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$name` as a public var into your class.
Like this:

```
class db_connect {
    // We declare a public var
    public $name = "";

    function settings() {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM lms_admin_settings";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->name = $data["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to access your var like this in `index.php`:

```
$data = new db_connect;
$data->settings();
echo $data->name;
```

You can read this to learn more about vars and function visibility 
[Php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: I tried it, it shows no error but no result; didn't echo the `$name` variable or simply does nothing.

Comment: Did you run `$data->settings();` like before ?

Comment: I made it work by changing `$name = $data["name"];` to `$this->name=$data["name"];` from your code. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class db_connect {

    // Other functions and variables here
    public $name;
    function settings() {

        $sql="SELECT * FROM lms_admin_settings";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->name = $data["name"];
        }
    }
}

//index.php
include("class.library.php");
$data = new db_connect;
$data->settings();
echo($data->name);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you're not returning anything from the `settings()` method. Return the entire result set from the `settings()` method and loop through it, like this:

**class.library.php**

```
class db_connect {

    // Other functions and variables here

    function settings() {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM lms_admin_settings";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include("class.library.php");
$data = new db_connect;

// catch the result set
$result = $data->settings();

// loop through the result set
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // display
    echo $data['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yup, this works but I don't actually want to put `fetch_assoc()` outside the function. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @RonnelMartinez Glad to know that the issue is resolved, but in the [accepted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35091841/5517143) you will only get the `name` from the last row because in each iteration of `while()` loop you're re-writing the instance variable `$name`. So fix it.